# Does "I haven't got to do it yet" imply not completing sth but having enough time to make it?

Tags: present-perfect, expressions, phrasal-verbs

I wanted to express a similar meaning to the one of this sentence: 
`I haven't get it done yet`, but at the same time, I wanted to emphasise that I had enough time, but was, say, too lazy to complete this thing.

So, is the sentence

> ***"I haven't got to do it yet."***

grammatically correct and does it fit the context I provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say

> I haven't gotten it done yet.

which is often used if I have started on it but not finished.  I might also also say simply

> I haven't done it yet.

or

> I haven't gotten around to it yet.

which implies that I have been doing other things instead and have not yet started on it.  It was too low in my priorities.

Comment: I don't know why but I really thought I would see a sentence with the phrase `get to` somewhere there... Doesn't it mean to start/ take up something? Please correct me if I'm totally off, I'll be really grateful!

Comment: @Aduku - You might be thinking of **I haven't gotten to do it yet**, which means something like "I have not had the chance to do it."

Comment: @Aduku *I have not gotten to it yet* is essentially the same as *I have not gotten around to it yet*, and is likely what you are thinking about.

Comment: @Aduku gotten is american English, Your version is correct in British English.